# Get the currently focused control of a non-foreground window?

Tags: c#, excel, winapi, com, office-addins

I have a tool that automates excel by requesting Excel refresh with `Application.Calculate` - the problem is that (surprisingly) calling `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.Calculate` will kick the user out of the current action if they are in the middle of editing a cell, renaming a sheet, typing in a ribbon control (like the font box), etc... (That problem described here: [Calling Application.Calculate breaks formula being edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221237))

To counter this, I was able to use WinApi calls to detect whether one of several "edit" controls is active. If I detect the Excel user is "Busy", I simply pause automation to avoid interrupting their editing.

```
public static bool IsExcelBusy(Application xlApp, out string reason)
{
    IntPtr excelHwnd = (IntPtr)xlApp.Hwnd;
    uint excelThreadId = NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(excelHwnd, out uint excelProcessId);
    // Get the handle of whatever window is in the foreground (system-wide)
    IntPtr foreground = NativeMethods.GetForegroundWindow();

    // Problem: If a non-excel-owned process has focus, we cannot get the focused control
    uint foregroundThreadId = NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(foreground, out uint foregroundProcessId);
    if (foregroundProcessId != excelProcessId)
        return false; // How can we know what control has focus?
    // Otherwise, the following works:
    try
    {
        // We need to attach the thread that owns this window to get the focused control
        uint thisThreadId = NativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId();
        NativeMethods.AttachThreadInput(foregroundThreadId, thisThreadId, true);
        IntPtr focusedControlHandle = NativeMethods.GetFocus();
        if (focusedControlHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // Get the class name of the control that the user is currently interacting with (if any)
            StringBuilder classNameResult = new StringBuilder(256);
            NativeMethods.GetClassName(focusedControlHandle, classNameResult, 256);
            string className = classNameResult.ToString();
            // Determine if this control is at risk of being interrupted by a recalculations
            switch (className)
            {
                case "EXCEL6":
                    reason = "User is editing a cell";
                    return true;
                case "EXCEL<":
                    reason = "User is editing in the formula bar";
                    return true;
                case "RICHEDIT60W":
                    reason = "User is editing a ribbon control";
                    return true;
                case "Edit":
                    isActivitySensitive = true;
                    reason = "User is in the named range box";
                    return true;
                case "EXCEL=":
                    isActivitySensitive = true;
                    reason = "User is renaming a sheet";
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        NativeMethods.AttachThreadInput(foregroundThreadId, thisThreadId, false);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem (as highlighted in the comments above) is that the `GetFocus()` WinApi call only works on the current foreground window. What I really want to know is what control has focus in the main Excel application window, regardless of whether that window is currently active.

For example, if the user is in the middle of typing a formula (calculations pause) and the user alt-tabs over to the browser to google something, I don't want to un-suspend automation or their half-typed formula will be lost.

I'm pretty sure what I need next is some winapi function akin to "GetFocus" but that gets the "active" or "focused" control for an application window that doesn't happen to currently be in the foreground.

I'm trying to avoid having to monitor the user's every action to track as they leave and re-enter the excel application. I'm looking for as light-weight and stateless a check as possible to determine whether, at any given instance, the user is in the middle of an edit operation in the Excel application.

Comment: It's worth commenting that the reason I'm not using other "tricks" going around for detecting whether an Excel user is in edit mode (like `Application.Interactive = False`) is that even these COM actions will "kick" the user out of actions such as renaming sheets. I need a test for user activity that's truly unobtrusive, and Excel doesn't offer one out-of-the-box.

Comment: Only the foreground window has a control with focus.  In total, only one control ever has focus.  It sounds like you are way-over complicating whatever it is you are doing, and therefore, commands are overlapping and become confused,

Comment: @ashleedawg how would one refer to the control that *would have* focus once you returned to the application window, but is currently not focused because another application has focus. I can only think of the term "active control". Even if words elude me, hopefully you tell what I mean just by jumping around between apps on your PC.

Comment: @ashleedawg It's not that complicated. It's like an app that wants to send a push notification to a user, but not if they're driving. There may be an API call for "is the user diving" today, but there wasn't always. So they needed to use heuristics. Excel does not have an API call or well established heuristics for determining if the user is editing a formula, but that doesn't mean an well-meaning developer using Excel automation shouldn't try to find that information out.

Answer (score 1):

[Each thread gets its own focus window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131016-00/?p=2913) (supposedly) but you can't really access it when the window is not active. `GetGUIThreadInfo` returns NULL values when the window is not active:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(...);
DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL);
GUITHREADINFO gti;
gti.cbSize = sizeof(GUITHREADINFO);
if (GetGUIThreadInfo(tid, &gti))
{
    printf("hwndFocus=%p hwndActive=%p\n", gti.hwndFocus, gti.hwndActive);
}
```

At the Win32 level [the code has to restore the focus](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140521-00/?p=943) to the correct control manually when you switch to the application: ...[handling of the WM_ACTIVATE and WM_SETFOCUS messages to preserve the focus when the user switches away from the window and back](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031021-00/?p=42083).

You could try [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation), Office generally has good support for it and might expose activation/focus information for its controls.